# Accessing results from a method in another Class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, methods

Hi I am trying to get the results from a method that is in another class than mine. The method is a class method in CalculatorBrain.m. The problem is the Class method uses a instance variables that the other class graphingView.m doesnt have stored in it. GraphingView only gets called when a button is clicked and is segued to. How do I call this class method without the proper variables to start the method?

This method is stored in calculator brain. I want to access it in graphingView

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues
{
  NSMutableArray *stack;
  if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
      stack = [program mutableCopy];
  }

  return [self popOperandOffProgramStack:stack];
}
```

So far I have this:

```
[CalculatorBrain runProgram:<#(id)#> usingVariableValues:<#(NSDictionary *)#>
```

I dont know how to put in the values I had to the instance variables in calculator brain.

Answer (score 1):

Save the results to a property and then you can access them in another class.

(I'm assuming you're in the same view controller and are accessing both models from it.)

Comment: If you wanted to be really cool, you could use assembly to save it to a register, just saying...

Comment: Im in a different view controller and it is saved in a property

Comment: Then there are three ways to do that.

You can 
- (a) pass that property through to your other view controller
- (b) import that class into your view controller and call the method again 
- (c) declare a global variable and set it to that (slightly overkill though)